# Collection of sci-fi short stories I read in the '90s. One story was about a girl and boy with powers who'd been raised on a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, space, anthology-book

I think there was a hand on the cover which looked like it was pushing through/covered by a type of material. The last or near-last story was about a girl and boy with powers who'd been raised on a spaceship (?) and they weren't allowed to be together as they had higher purpose. Right at the end, during a final struggle with the people who raised them and are trying to keep them apart, he tells her to let time spin or something like that, as a form of possible annihilation or escape? Any ideas would be really helpful, it's been haunting me for well over a decade!

I think the author was a man. I think it definitely was more on the young adult side of writing. The title of the collection of short stories/the book could have been one word. The couple in the last story I'm referring to were raised by these people who tried to keep them apart/stop them falling in love and, I think, were slightly scared of their powers.

Comment: What does "with powers" mean? They could read minds, or levitate, or what?

Comment: It's really hard to remember specifics, I just remember that towards the end/at the end she's instructed (by him because they're cornered/captured) to let herself go by spinning time/using the full force of her power - she's been taught to restrict and stop herself going too far, but then at the end she let's go and that's the end of the story.